# Docusign gem block request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, docusignapi

I'm using the DocuSign ruby client (https://github.com/docusign/docusign-ruby-client) on ruby on rails to send a document via email to some clients, but when I deploy the project after 15 minutes the request between the application and DocuSign gets "paused". For some reason the gem creates the request but doesn't send it as you can see in the next image where I enable the debug in the gem:

[image]

In that point the log doesn't print any more after 15 minutes.

The code that send the message in my app is:

```rb
access_token = "xxxxxxx"

account_id = "xxxxxxxxx"

base_path = "xxxxxxxxxx"

envelope_args = {
  signer_email: contact.email,
  signer_name: contact.name,
  template_id: document.docusign_id
}

@args = {
  account_id: account_id,
  base_path: base_path,
  access_token: access_token,
  envelope_args: envelope_args
}

envelope_args = @args[:envelope_args]
# 1. Create the envelope request object

envelope_definition = make_envelope(envelope_args)

# 2. Call Envelopes::create API method
# Exceptions will be caught by the calling function
envelope_api = create_envelope_api(@args)
envelope_api.create_envelope @args[:account_id], envelope_definition
```

I don't know what can I do.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We looked for the issue in our code, but we saw that in the step which the request is send in the gem [here](https://github.com/docusign/docusign-ruby-client/blob/21be361feb7dcf8e34f4d3df2412dedff41c20d5/lib/docusign_esign/client/api_client.rb#L54) always freezes. So we debugged there and we saw that curl was being used for ruby. At that point we saw that curl was trying to reconnect with Docusign but it wasn't success, so we found this issue in the version of curl that we had (https://github.com/curl/curl/issues/4499 )

To fix it we updated the version to the latest, and it fixed the issue.

Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

Your screenshot shows everything happening at 18:29:05 -- I don't understand the issue.

Also, have you tried install/using the [RoR code example](https://github.com/docusign/code-examples-ruby)?
See if it has the same problem.

Comment: the hour is because it is with UTC, all it application is running with that hour, and the code is taken from https://github.com/docusign/code-examples-ruby/blob/master/app/services/eg009_service.rb, the problem is that when I deploy the app, it runs but after 15 minutes when my app try to send a request to docusign, the client freeze and doesn't send the request.

Comment: To debug, start with our example which is (we think) known good. If you can reproduce the problem there, then the example has a bug. Otherwise, your app has a bug. Use binary search to narrow down the issue.